# Atom HTML snippet not working on macOS?

Tags: atom-editor

I have an html snippet in my `snippets.cson` file in my atom 1.21.1 on macOS, 
it doesn't report any errors,
when I open my index.html file and begin to type the prefix nothing appears.

```
'.text.html.basic':
      'tasks table':
        'prefix': 'ttable'
        'body': """
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Declare an assignment</th>
                        <th>Start</th>
                        <th>End</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">AM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wake up</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lunch</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            """
```

While my Python and jQuery snippets seem to be working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong with '.text.html.basic':

change to '.text.html':